# How to get decoded barcode height from camera images in c++ zxing library

Tags: visual-c++, zxing

How to determind or find barcode height from camera image or image file.Here am using zxing c++ library for decode barcode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ZXing C++ Port, you don't need to find (startX, startY) or (endX, endY). You can use Leptonica lib. I think it will be faster

Firstly, using pixRead() to read input image, save into Pix* format.
Then, convert Pix* to BinaryBimap and use decode() method from class Reader of ZXing directly!

If you still have any problem or don't know, I can send you about detail code

Comment: Decoding is not matter here find RECT(X,Y,width,height) of Barcode?

Comment: I wonder why you are looking for it while you're using ZXing C++ because ZXing C++ have a default decode() method. You just get raw data of image and pass it as parameter to decode() method of ZXing. In addition, as you may know, we have a lot of barcodes, and ZXing can decode about 15 types. So, corresponding to each barcode, you can read source code of ZXing C++ from Github for more detail